# How to reshape rows into columns on the basis of group in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My dataset contains groups, the primary is in the same row as the secondary but the third individual (listed in the database as a 2nd secondary or 3rd secondary) gets put in another row.

I have attempted to use self-joins and group-by

```
Primary  Secondary  
a        b         
a        c       
d        e          
f        NULL
```

I would like it to look something like this

```
Primary  Secondary    Third 
a        b            c                  
d        e            NULL         
f        NULL         Null
```

Comment: Your statements ***imply*** that first result set is the results of a query you've haven't shown us. Instead show us your attempt and what your data looks like as it's stored. We can't help you get from "A to B", when we don't know where "A" is (and instead you've given us "C").

Comment: Group by is used to split data into all the combinations present in the data. If a is combined with b and c the group by will return two rows! Do you want them on the same row? In what shape? What if there is 4th secondary? Which secondary should be displayed in "Secondary" and which in "Third"?

Comment: Warning: Is this really THE problem? Maybe you are hung up on some small part of your task, and we can solve the bigger one. If so reconsider looking up the bigger problem first. I may have an naswer on stackoverflow already. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, you can do what you want, but you cannot control which columns get which values -- unless a column specifies the ordering.

So:

```
select primary, min(secondary) as secondary,
       (case when min(secondary) <> max(secondary) then max(secondary) end) as third
from t
group by primary;
```

Comment: Because I wanted to make the issue as simple as possible I did not mention that this data-set contains up to 5 secondary individuals, it also contains other numbers such as discount codes which cannot be added to the min max functions as the respective code may not be the min or the max

Comment: @DominicNaimool . . . You oversimplified the question.  This answers the question that you asked.  I would suggest that you ask a more relevant question as a *new* question.